# From JSP Write to XML

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am going to design front end using JSP containing Start date, End date etc.. Finally i have to read these into Java object and write it as XML file. How could i accomplish this.. Please Help me on this requirement.

Thanks,
Narayan

Comment: Follow the servlets and get the Parameter which are required and generate the XML file using xml generating  API's in java like  JDOM, JAXB and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the input in JSP and pass it to the Servlet. Then you can use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) to  write to the XML.( I assume that you write the XML on the server, if you need to write the XML on the client computer  - just import the xstream package iito your JSP header and put the servlet code snippet in your JSP)

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*, com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream" %>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Handle Current Date & Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Display Current Date & Time</h1>
        </center>
        <%
            Date date = new Date();
            // initialize date from input
            // ...pass the date to the servlet
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

in the servlet code :

```
Date date = /* get the date from the request*/
// then do something like this:
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("date", Date.class);
String xml = xstream.toXML(date);
// write the xml string to the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using any`XML Parser`.In  Jsp page get the attribute value (Start Date , End Date etc.) and the create XML using `DOM` api.Below is simple example.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    Element startDate= doc.createElement("startDate");
    startDate.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(<your_Value>));
    doc.appendChild(startDate);

    // lastname elements
    Element endtDate= doc.createElement("endtDate");
    endtDate.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(<your_Value>));
    doc.appendChild(endtDate);

   TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);
```